# How can I retrieve titles of various articles from one website using python web scraping?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web

I am looking to get topic of all the articles available in this webpage "  " using python web crawler. I am very new to html. This is the code I have so far which I got as a reference from different examples. Would somebody please help me undersand this and get the correct code?

The code below is what I tried changing h2 tag to h1, h3,h4 and so on.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

from urllib2 import HTTPError

from urllib2 import URLError

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

try:

     html = urlopen("https://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/#/*/365days/")
except HTTPError as e:

    print(e)

except URLError:

    print("Server down or incorrect domain")

else:

    res = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),'html.parser')

    tags = res.findAll("h2", {"class": "widget-title"})


    for tag in tags:

        print(tag.getText())
```

My expected outcome is titles of various new articles in this webpage. For eg:

Judge Harshly Criticizes Kobach During Contempt Hearing

How a Self-Driving Uber Killed a Pedestrian in Arizona

Comment: what have you tried so far?  what is the specific outcome you were expecting?  how is your outcome different from what's expected?

Comment: That page is populated using javascript. You'll need to either use a headless browser like the one included in the selenium package or call make the same request that the page ends up making instead of trying to load the page itself.

Comment: @MohammadAthar Thanks for the feedback, I have edited my question.   I am fairly new to this topic so if you can help would be great.

Comment: @wpercy Thank you for the information. I did not understand the part making the same request that the page ends up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you go to the page

```
https://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/#/*/365days/
```

there is javascript that is executed on pageload which requests the resource living at

```
https://query.nytimes.com/svc/add/v1/sitesearch.json?begin_date=365daysago&facet=true
```

This responds with a very large JSON document containing the results of your search, which you can parse to get back the article headlines. The code would look something like:

```
import json
from urllib2 import urlopen, HTTPError, URLError

resp = urlopen("https://query.nytimes.com/svc/add/v1/sitesearch.json?q=quack&begin_date=365daysago&facet=true")
content = resp.read()
j = json.loads(content)

articles = j['response']['docs']

headlines = [ article['headline']['main'] for article in articles ]
print headlines
```